# React Native Remote JSON config file react native

Tags: react-native

I have a file; config.js, were I put all of my string settings for calling WordPress, images URLs, JSON URLs, etc...

I want to be able to set a remote local (URI) to pull back a JSON file and then use those properties instead if the setting user_remote_config is set to 1.

Two challenges I've had are;

- I don't want to use Firebase remote config
- When I've used the same approach for returning a JSON file (useEffect or useState), I have invalid hook use as the config is called from other pages that already implement useEffect.

  ```
  let use_remote_config = 0;
   if (use_remote_config == 1) {
   // Add in here remote config file fetch - Pull in JSON file
   }

   const config = {  
       wpurl: 'https://public-api.wordpress.com/wp/v2/sites/xxx.com/posts',
       player_profiles: 'https://xxx.json',
       fixtures: 'https://xxx',
       youtube_url: 'https://xxx',
       mens_wp_cat_id: '7319491',
       womens_wp_cat_id: '992080',
       news_article_no_returned: 40,
       no_image: 'https://xxx.png',
       assests_url: 'https://xxx',
   }

   export default config;
  ```

If anyone has an example of setting up remote configurations, or links to examples that would be a great share as I've been looking and everything references the Firebase remote config examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a useEffect hook to fetch your configuration when your app opens. For example: `App.js`.

After fetch the configuration you can share with all the app by using **Context API** or **React Redux Thunk** using

```js
<Provider />
```

> You can check the documentation of Context API here https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html.

In this way you can avoid that all pages of your app fetch the configuration all the time.